# Selenium chrome and safari WebDriver “find_element_by_xpath” on WebElement

Tags: python, macos, google-chrome, selenium, safari

I have been trying to make my code work on chrome (Windows 7), and it definitely worked on safari running OSx

Here's the code for OSx:

```
    import time 
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    driver = webdriver.Safari()

    driver.get('https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.com')

    opp = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'com_TI-B')]/@onclick")

    to_be_visited = []
    p = re.compile('contentForm\:j_idt\d+\:j_id\d+\:j_id\d+')


    for x in opp:
        doc_ids = (p.findall(x.text)[0])
        to_be_visited.append(doc_ids)
```

heres the code for Chrome:

```
        import time 
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import csv
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    driver.get('https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com')

    opp = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@class,"com_TI-B")]/@onclick')

    to_be_visited = []
    p = re.compile('contentForm\:j_idt\d+\:j_id\d+\:j_id\d+')
    print(p)

    for x in opp:
        doc_ids = (p.findall(x.text)[0])
        to_be_visited.append(doc_ids)
```

its my first time using selenium, and i keep getting errors such as

"The result of the xpath expression "//a[contains(@class,"com_TI-B"
)]/@onclick" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element."

I am wondering if there are difference between chrome and safari's webdriver?